# How to change CLIPS default help file path to custom path?

Tags: linux, clips

I was recently started work on CLIPS Programming for developing Expert System. Since all command structure is very new for me i started seeking command assistance using (help) command. but CLIPS Shell throws cant open help file as follows.

```
CLIPS> (help)
Loading help file entries from ${prefix}/share/clips/clips.hlp.
Please wait...
[TEXTPRO1] Could not open file "${prefix}/share/clips/clips.hlp".
CLIPS> (exit)
```

and my wish is to know where and how to set CLIPS help file path to custom CLIPS installed path.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default help path by modifying the value of HELP_DEFAULT in setup.h and recompiling CLIPS. You can also change the path using the help-path function:

```
         CLIPS (V6.24 06/15/06)
CLIPS> (help)
Loading help file entries from clips.hlp.
Please wait...
[TEXTPRO1] Could not open file "clips.hlp".
CLIPS> (help-path)
The current help entries file is clips.hlp
CLIPS> (help-path "../clips.hlp")
Help entries file reset to ../clips.hlp
CLIPS> (help)
Loading help file entries from ../clips.hlp.
Please wait...


HELP_USAGE                 FUNCTION_SUMMARY
RELEASE_NOTES              COMMAND_SUMMARY
CONSTRUCT_SUMMARY          INTEGRATED_EDITOR

MAIN Topic?
```